# SVN hook / svn up / conflict

Tags: svn

When I do a Svn up in a file with a local modification that can produce a conflict.

Is it possible to cancel svn update with a hook and write a message?

Thanks

Comment: This should be on serverfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?  Just resolve the conflict by choosing your copy of the file (you could even do this automatically on update with `--accept mine-conflict`).

Comment: i don't want someone do a update of a directory on production site, don't see the conflict & go on week end ! i would like do it in server side to stop update if a conflict is detected, is it possible ?

Comment: Updates are client-side and there is no reason why it should matter if someone leaves a conflict in their working copy.  If rather than update you mean `commit`, you don't need to worry because you can't commit if there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think there is a subversion hook for svn update